# End to end test of UI features that show up after a long delay (5 minutes)

Tags: e2e-testing, cypress

I'm trying to use an end to end test runner to test that a modal shows up after a delay of 5 minutes.

The app is a single page web app, in this case React, and the testing framework, Cypress, and this has to run in a CircleCI build and deployment pipeline, with multiple environments (testing, staging, prod)

Here are the constraints I have:

1. I cannot wait 5 minutes for something that would take 50ms to test
2. If I make the delay configurable in the app's configuration, then all tests that go through this page will have a modal showing in 50ms instead of 5 minutes, polluting all other tests.
3. I'd prefer not to add hooks in the app just for the purpose of testing

Is there a clean way to test this without delay, keeping it overall very fast?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`cy.clock()`](https://on.cypress.io/clock) to programmatically control all the time-related functions, including `setTimeout`.

Something like this should work:

```js
// in your Cypress test...
cy.clock() // activate the clock mocking
// do your cy.visit() after cy.clock()
cy.tick(5 * 60 * 1000) // move time forwards 5 minutes
expect('.my-time-delay-modal').to.exist
```

There are [more examples in the documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock.html#No-Args).

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a clean solution. The application code isn't using setTimeout directly, but, a redux effect called delay, import { delay } from 'redux-saga/effects', which i hope is using setTimeout under the hood. I will give it shot and see.